# Create iframes showing the end of each one as if I had dragged the scrollbar to the end

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

In short: what I only need is this graphic map and the team symbol, without the other data appearing on the screen, wasting space and without the scrollbar on the right side that covers the end of the graphic.

```js
var myIframe = document.getElementById('iframe');
myIframe.onload = function(){
    myIframe.contentWindow.scrollTo(0,500);
};
```

```html
<iframe id="iframe" src="https://www.sofascore.com/event/9626475/attack-momentum/embed"></iframe>
```

When creating the `iframe`, it comes with some unwanted data that only takes up space, as I left circled in the image below:

[image]

When I decrease the size of the `iframe` to take up less space, this happens:

[image]

What I would like to happen is that when creating the `iframe`, it would already scroll to the end, thus automatically:

[image]

Is there anything I can put in my `HTML` or `script` that can do this automatic scrolling when creating `iframes`?

I also tried using `.style("margin-top","-90px");` but doing so happens that the values exceed the `iframe` limits getting on top of the previous ones:

[image]

**If you want to do the complete test, use this code and create a CSV file with the sofascore ids (`SofaScore_Live.csv`):**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            .vl {
            border-left: 3px solid red;
            height: 1000px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 30.3%;
            margin-left: -3px;
            top: 0;
            }
            .vl2 {
            border-left: 3px solid red;
            height: 1000px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 10.9%;
            margin-left: -3px;
            top: 0;
            }
            .vl3 {
            border-left: 3px solid red;
            height: 1000px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 69%;
            margin-left: -3px;
            top: 0;
            }
            .matches {
            text-align:center;
            float: left;
            width: 700px;
            border: 1px solid white;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            }
            .column {
            text-align:center;
            float: left;
            width: 700px;
            border: 1px solid white;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            }
            .grid {
            float: left;
            width: 100%;
            }
            .row:after {
            content: "";
            display: table;
            clear: both;
            }
            .button {
            background-color: #33ccff;
            color: black;
            font-weight: bold;
            }
            input[type=submit] {
            background-color: #33ccff;
            color: black;
            font-weight: bold;
            }
            html {
            overflow: scroll;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            }
            ::-webkit-scrollbar {
            width: 0px; /* remove scrollbar space /
            background: transparent; / optional: just make scrollbar invisible /
            }
            / optional: show position indicator in red */
            ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
            background: #FF0000;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.1.1/d3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3-fetch@3"></script>
        </script>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color:black;">
        <div class="vl"></div>
        <div class="vl2"></div>
        <div class="vl3"></div>
        <div style="color:white;font-weight:bold" class="grid games" id="jogos-sofascore">
        </div>
            <script id="script-da-caixa-de-selecao-suspensa-5">
                var select_5 = d3.select("#jogos-sofascore")
                .append("div")
                .attr("id","select-box-5")
                .style("width","100%")

                function valorparaiframe(iframevalue) {
                    let link = iframevalue;
                        return "https://www.sofascore.com/event/" + iframevalue + "/attack-momentum/embed";
                }

                async function update() {

                    let data = await d3.csv("./SofaScore_Live.csv");

                    let update_5 = select_5.selectAll(".matches")
                        .data(data,d=>d.id);
                    
                    update_5.exit().remove();

                    // Enter new divs:
                    const enter = update_5.enter()
                        .append("div")
                        .attr("class","matches");
                    
                    // Append the children to entered divs:
                    enter.append("iframe")
                        .attr("src",d => valorparaiframe(d.id))
                        .style("width","100%")
                        .style("height","110");
                }
                
                update();
                    setInterval(update,60000);
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

`SofaScore_Live.csv` CSV example:

```
id
9576375
9602988
9643997
9944904
9591418
9595065
9595129
9595043
9671970
9698797
9671975
9671974
9578901
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iframe`s loaded from a different origin are protected by the [same-origin-policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy), which prevents you from accessing/modifying the content of it (which is why you can't use `scrollTo` etc,.).

As a workaround, if you know the height of the content in the `iframe` (which you can retrieve by going to the `iframe` source and getting the body's `offsetHeight`), you can set the height of the `iframe` to the height of the content. Then, you can wrap the `iframe` in a container, set the container's `height`, and scroll to the bottom of the container.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.iframe-container')
container.scrollTop = container.scrollHeight;
```

```css
iframe {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
}

.iframe-container{
  height:120px;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="iframe-container">
  <iframe id="iframe" src="https://www.sofascore.com/event/9626475/attack-momentum/embed"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Spetric, thank you very much for the answear. Would it be too much to ask you to show me a model so that when there is more than 1 game, it can do this function in all containers even if they have the same name? If possible, thank you very much!

Comment: @BrondbyIF you can iterate through every element with that specific name and scroll to the bottom, like so: `document.querySelectorAll('[name=youriframecontainername]').forEach(e => e.scrollTop = e.scrollHeight)`

Comment: Hi @Spetric Unfortunately when I do this, the first game rolls the perfect amount, but when there are several games, the others go up much more than they should until the last game doesn't even show up the map because it rolled down so much.

Comment: Hi @Spetric Actually the problem happens when I try to create two columns with games on the same line, I'll tinker to try to solve it, thanks a lot!

Comment: @BrondbyIF are the iframes all of the same source? Currently, my code will set a fixed height for all iframes. You may need to give each iframe a different height.

Comment: Hi mate, ia create a new question for this specific problem! Thanks in advance (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70247706/how-to-equalize-the-starting-position-of-iframes-to-scroll-to-the-bottom-of-the)

Comment: @BrondbyIF I've posted a answer on the other question. Sorry about the late response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the scroll(x, y) function:
`scroll(0, 10000)`

Comment: Hi @BalaM314, i try using ```.scroll(0, 10000)``` along with the other iframe creation data ```enter.append("iframe")```, but did not work. Could you give me a hint on how I could specify how it should scroll the iframe instead of the page? Thanks!