# How to equalize the starting position of iframes to scroll to the bottom of the page?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

The idea is that all iframes show the end of the page, where the pressure map is. But when they are created, iframes don't appear in the same starting position, so when I try to scroll them all down, some cross the threshold!

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            iframe {
                height: 200px;
                width: 100%;
                border: none;
            }
            .iframe-container {
                height: 120px;
                width: 700px;
                overflow: auto;
                overflow: hidden;
                float: left;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color:black;">
        <div class="grid games" id="jogos-sofascore">
            <div id="select-box-5" style="width: 100%;">
                <div class="iframe-container" >
                    <iframe id="iframe" src="https://www.sofascore.com/event/9985319/attack-momentum/embed"></iframe>
                </div>
                <div class="iframe-container">
                    <iframe id="iframe" src="https://www.sofascore.com/event/9985309/attack-momentum/embed"></iframe>
                </div>
                <div class="iframe-container">
                    <iframe id="iframe" src="https://www.sofascore.com/event/9992075/attack-momentum/embed"></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            function atualizar() {
                document.querySelectorAll('.iframe-container').forEach(e => e.scrollTop = e.scrollHeight)
            }
            setInterval(atualizar,5000);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried using a way to scroll to the top and then to the end:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.iframe-container').forEach(e => e.scrollTop = 0)
document.querySelectorAll('.iframe-container').forEach(e => e.scrollTop = e.scrollHeight)
```

But it didn't work, the iframes weren't scrolled to the beginning as they should.

How could I solve this problem making the scroll-to-end-of-page event malleable regardless of the start position of iframes?

Expected Result:

[image]

Current Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the height of the `iframe` to the height of the content.

Currently, you are setting the height of each iframe to `200px`. However, the height of the content varies for each individual source. If the height of the source of the `iframe` is less than `200px`, you will "overscroll". In this case, you can to apply a specific `height` to each `iframe`.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.iframe-container').forEach(e => e.scrollTop = e.scrollHeight)
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            iframe {
                width: 100%;
                border: none;
            }
            .iframe-container {
                height: 120px;
                width: 700px;
                overflow: auto;
                overflow: hidden;
                float: left;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color:black;">
        <div class="grid games" id="jogos-sofascore">
            <div id="select-box-5" style="width: 100%;">
                <div class="iframe-container" >
                    <iframe id="iframe" src="https://www.sofascore.com/event/9985319/attack-momentum/embed" height="200"></iframe>
                </div>
                <div class="iframe-container">
                    <iframe id="iframe" src="https://www.sofascore.com/event/9985309/attack-momentum/embed" height="155"></iframe>
                </div>
                <div class="iframe-container">
                    <iframe id="iframe" src="https://www.sofascore.com/event/9992075/attack-momentum/embed" height="155"></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note that you can get the height of the content of the `iframe` by going to the source of it and getting the body's `offsetHeight` (e.g, `document.body.offsetHeight`).

Comment: Hello friend, thanks for the support. The problem is that if I change the links to other games, the error will happen again due to the chance of iframes have other heights, correct? Is there a malleable way so that regardless of size, it can scroll the perfect amount for each one without me creating the iframe specifying its size?

Comment: I honestly don't know if I managed to explain very well, anything you can ask me, I make a point of explaining it again in another way.

Comment: When possible, if you can help me, I will try to give you some Bountie that I can give

Comment: @BrondbyIF There doesn't appear to be a way to do it purely front-end, at least. If you had a server that could send requests to the site, then it might be possible.

Comment: Hi mate @Spectric I have access to the chart data api, I am thinking that I will have to create my own charts!

Comment: @BrondbyIF OK :). Sorry I wasn't able to help.

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.iframe-container').forEach(e => e.scrollTop = e.scrollHeight)
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            iframe {
                width: 100%;
                border: none;
            }
            .iframe-container {
                height: 120px;
                width: 700px;
                overflow: auto;
                overflow: hidden;
                float: left;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color:black;">
        <div class="grid games" id="jogos-sofascore">
            <div id="select-box-5" style="width: 100%;">
                <div class="iframe-container" >
                    <iframe id="iframe" src="https://www.sofascore.com/event/9985319/attack-momentum/embed" height="200"></iframe>
                </div>
                <div class="iframe-container">
                    <iframe id="iframe" src="https://www.sofascore.com/event/9985309/attack-momentum/embed" height="155"></iframe>
                </div>
                <div class="iframe-container">
                    <iframe id="iframe" src="https://www.sofascore.com/event/9992075/attack-momentum/embed" height="155"></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.iframe-container').forEach(e => e.scrollTop = e.scrollHeight)
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            iframe {
                width: 100%;
                border: none;
            }
            .iframe-container {
                height: 120px;
                width: 700px;
                overflow: auto;
                overflow: hidden;
                float: left;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color:black;">
        <div class="grid games" id="jogos-sofascore">
            <div id="select-box-5" style="width: 100%;">
                <div class="iframe-container" >
                    <iframe id="iframe" src="https://www.sofascore.com/event/9985319/attack-momentum/embed" height="200"></iframe>
                </div>
                <div class="iframe-container">
                    <iframe id="iframe" src="https://www.sofascore.com/event/9985309/attack-momentum/embed" height="155"></iframe>
                </div>
                <div class="iframe-container">
                    <iframe id="iframe" src="https://www.sofascore.com/event/9992075/attack-momentum/embed" height="155"></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

https://games.app.goo.gl/xBJcfuDt4gSMEDe96

Comment: It would be nice to give a brief explanation of how this works / how it solves the problem, and how it's different than existing answers.